# NotFoundError when use tf.slim.evaluation.evaluate_once

Tags: tensorflow

When I wanted to evaluate my model use slim.evaluation.evaluate_once() function, encountered NotFoundError. It told me can not find key or value for the model. like this:

```
Running evaluation Loop...
INFO:tensorflow:Starting evaluation at 2017-08-25-11:40:57
INFO:tensorflow:Starting evaluation at 2017-08-25-11:40:57
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from tmp/flowers/finetune_log/model.ckpt-5000
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from tmp/flowers/finetune_log/model.ckpt-5000

NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/wangx/Dev_env/.tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1326     try:
-> 1327       return fn(*args)
   1328     except errors.OpError as e:

/home/wangx/Dev_env/.tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run_fn(session, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1305                                    feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1306                                    status, run_metadata)
   1307 

/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py in __exit__(self, type, value, traceback)
     65             try:
---> 66                 next(self.gen)
     67             except StopIteration:

...
NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Key InceptionV1/Mixed_4c/Branch_0/Conv2d_0a_1x1/biases not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save/RestoreV2_44 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2_44/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2_44/shape_and_slices)]]
     [[Node: save/RestoreV2_6/_1 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_238_save/RestoreV2_6", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]
```

I save my checkpoint at ./tmp/flowers/finetune_log, and the flowers photos is downloaded following the tutorial. Is there something wrong with the checkpoint file I got from the training? or I missed something when I did evaluation? here is my evaluation code:

```
from datasets import flowers
from nets import inception

with tf.Graph().as_default():
    tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)
    tf_global_step = slim.get_or_create_global_step()
    dataset = flowers.get_split('validation', 'tmp/flowers')
    images, labels = load_batch(dataset)
    logits, endpoints = inception.inception_v1(images, num_classes=dataset.num_classes, is_training=False)
    predictions =tf.argmax(logits, 1)

    # Define the metrics:
    names_to_values, names_to_updates = slim.metrics.aggregate_metric_map({
    'eval/Accuracy': slim.metrics.streaming_accuracy(predictions, labels),
    'eval/Recall': slim.metrics.streaming_recall(predictions, labels)})

    print('Running evaluation Loop...')
    checkpoint_path = tf.train.latest_checkpoint('tmp/flowers/finetune_log')

    metric_values = slim.evaluation.evaluate_once(
    num_evals=20,
    master='',
    checkpoint_path=checkpoint_path,
    logdir='tmp/flowers/eval_finetune_log',
    eval_op=names_to_updates.values(),
    final_op=names_to_values.values())
```

In case, here is my training code:

```
def get_init_fn():
    """Returns a function run by the chief worker to warm-start the training."""
    checkpoint_exclude_scopes=["InceptionV1/Logits", "InceptionV1/AuxLogits"]

    exclusions = [scope.strip() for scope in checkpoint_exclude_scopes]

    variables_to_restore = []
    for var in slim.get_model_variables():
        excluded = False
        for exclusion in exclusions:
            if var.op.name.startswith(exclusion):
                excluded = True
                break
        if not excluded:
            variables_to_restore.append(var)

    return slim.assign_from_checkpoint_fn(
      os.path.join('tmp/checkpoints', 'inception_v1.ckpt'),
      variables_to_restore)

train_dir = 'tmp/flowers/finetune_log'

with tf.Graph().as_default():
    dataset = flowers.get_split('train', 'tmp/flowers')
    images, labels = load_batch(dataset)

    with slim.arg_scope(inception.inception_v1_arg_scope()):
        logits, _ = inception.inception_v1(images, num_classes=dataset.num_classes, is_training=True)

    one_hot_labels = slim.one_hot_encoding(labels, 5)
    slim.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(logits, one_hot_labels)
    total_loss = slim.losses.get_total_loss()

    tf.summary.scalar('losses/Total Loss', total_loss)

    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
    train_op = slim.learning.create_train_op(total_loss, optimizer)

    final_loss = slim.learning.train(
        train_op,
        logdir=train_dir,
        init_fn=get_init_fn(),
        number_of_steps=5000,
        save_summaries_secs=1)

print('done.')
```

Thanks a lot. and it block me for long time.

Answer (score 0):

I found that in the evaluation snippet, if I do the following two change, the program can run:
1. define slim.arg_scope() for the model, I think this is the reason for NotFoundError beacuse program don't know the arguments like conv kernel size for the model, so the code should change like this:

```
images, labels = load_batch(dataset)
with slim.arg_scope(inception.inception_v1_arg_scope()):
    logits, _ = inception.inception_v1(images, num_classes=dataset.num_classes, is_training=True)
predictions =tf.argmax(logits, 1)
```

2.I remove slim.metrics.aggregate_metric_map(), and use a simple metric:

```
accuracy, accuracy_updates = slim.metrics.streaming_accuracy(predictions, labels)
```

and it can run now.